# Boxstarter fails to install package (extracted script is actually a zip file)

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, boxstarter

I'm trying to make a simple Boxstarter package that will install a few basics to new machines. Nothing special.
I've created a new package [as suggested in the docs](https://boxstarter.org/CreatingPackages) (using the Boxstarter shell):

```
New-BoxstarterPackage -Name MyPackage -Description "I hope you enjoy MyPackage"
```

I've ended up stripping everything I had in `tools/ChocolateyInstall.ps1` away and now it just contains:

```
Write-ChocolateySuccess "A success message"
```

I've then packaged this with:

```
Invoke-BoxstarterBuild MyPackage
```

I've then copied the resulting `MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg` file to a fresh machine that has Boxstarter installed on it and run with:

```
Install-BoxstarterPackage -PackageName "C:\Temp\MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg"
```

This is when I see errors:

```
ERROR: At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\tmp4CEB.tmp\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1:2 char:647
+ ... ∟MyPackage.nuspec ¢↑( ¶uPKNÄ0♀Ý#q‡¨ˆ;lP&#Ø! ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.

At C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\tmp4CEB.tmp\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1:2 char:651
+ ... Package.nuspec ¢↑( ¶uPKNÄ0♀Ý#q‡¨ˆ;lP&#Ø!Ä§,× ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
```

If I open the version of `ChocolateyInstall.ps1' from` C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter\BuildPackages\tmp4CEB.tmp\tools`, it looks corrupt:

[image: Screengrab of script file in notepad]

It also looks like it contains some XML.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That file you show in your screenshot is in fact a .ZIP file (starts with `PK` followed by byte 05 and 06, which is the [FOURCC Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/fourcc-codes) for a .zip )

Comment: Why does it have a .ps1 extension?
And why is Boxstarter (or Chocolatey) trying to run it as though it's a script?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue that you are having here is that you are providing a path directly to a nupkg.  As per the [help documentation for the Install-BoxstarterPackagecmdlet](https://github.com/chocolatey/boxstarter/blob/master/Boxstarter.Chocolatey/Install-BoxstarterPackage.ps1#L66), the PackageName property is expecting the following:

> The names of one or more NuGet Packages to be installed or URIs or
> file paths pointing to a Chocolatey script. If using package names,
> the .nupkg file for the provided package names are searched in the
> following locations and order:
>
> - .\BuildPackages relative to the parent directory of the module file
> - The Chocolatey community feed
> - NugetSources in Boxstarter.config when the 'DelegateChocoSources' switch is used

Can you please try by passing in the package name, using one of the suggested sources for the package?